# Lost labels using intertext with varioref and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, errors, amsmath, varioref

I have a problem using `\intertext` together with `\vref` when hyperref is also used. Consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{amsmath, varioref}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \label{kinetic-energy}
    E = mc^2
  \end{equation}
  \begin{gather}
      A \\
  \intertext{ and therefore due to \vref{kinetic-energy}: }
      B
  \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

which yields an error message of the pattern:

```
! Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label '1@xvr' will be lost.
```

at the end of the gather environment.

If I either comment out hyperref, *OR* use `\ref` instead of `\vref` the example works fine. I am using TeXLive 2011.

Have I encountered a package bug/conflict, or is there some remedial I have missed?

---

**UPDATE:**
I  tried the solution of Mico, and it works except for a slight incompatibility between cleveref and refstyle (sic); it misses a space between the equation number and the page reference. Adding this to the preamble after including cleveref seems to fix the problem:

```
\makeatletter
\let\withoutspacecref@@vpageref\cref@@vpageref
\renewcommand\cref@@vpageref{\space\withoutspacecref@@vpageref}
\makeatother
```

---

**Update 2023**: The problem shown above would no longer appear to be relevant as of 2023. Presumably, this is because the `varioref` and `hyperref` packages have both been modified in the intervening eleven years. For instance, `\vref` no longer outputs the string "on the same page" if the instruction occurs on the same page as the object being cross-referenced.

However, it's still the case that `hyperref` can cause problems for `\vref`. E.g., assume the commands

```
\usepackage[nospace]{varioref} 
    % since 2019, it's recommended to load varioref with the 'nospace' option
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
```

are executed in the preamble. Then, insert a `\clearpage` instruction after `equation` and before `align`. The output of the OP's MWE then is:

[image]

I'm not sure whether this is an outright bug, but the fact that "on the preceding page" is now part of the hyperlink is probably somewhat unexpected, to say the least.

In contrast, if `cleveref` is loaded, one gets this output:

[image]

I daresay that this is far closer to what most users might expect to get.

Hence, the recommendation stands: to avoid some unexpected interactions between `varioref` and `hyperref`, it helps to load `cleveref` as well -- *after* both `varioref` and `hyperref`, for sure.

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage[nospace]{varioref} % 'nospace' option is recommended since 2019
  \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
  \usepackage{cleveref} % <-- new
  
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \label{kinetic-energy}
    E = mc^2
  \end{equation}
\clearpage
\begin{gather}
      A \\
\intertext{and therefore, due to \vref{kinetic-energy}:}
      B
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `varioref` and `hyperref` are not fully compatible, so some bad interaction is to be expected.

Comment: @RolKau: Please see my edit based on your suggested edit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have indeed discovered a (mild) incompatibility between the `varioref` and `hyperref` packages. A solution to this problem is to load yet one more cross-referencing package, viz., the [cleveref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref) package. This approach would appear to work because `cleveref` modifies some of `varioref`'s internals in order to make `varioref` and `cleveref` cooperate better; in the process, `varioref` and `hyperref` also become mutually (more) compatible. Note that in the MWE below, the cross-referencing command that's executed is still `\vref` (and not, say, `\cref`).

Incidentally, the `cleveref` package should be loaded *later* than all other packages that perform cross-referencing tasks. In fact, it's highly advisable to load `cleveref` *last*, i.e., after all other packages have been loaded, simply because one may not know for sure whether or not the other packages might perform certain tasks -- however trivial they may seem at first -- that are related to LaTeX's cross-referencing mechanisms.

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{amsmath, varioref}
  \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % added 'colorlinks' option to make output 
                                    % show up in attached image file
  \usepackage{cleveref}  % new instruction
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \label{kinetic-energy}
    E = mc^2
  \end{equation}
  \begin{gather}
      A \\
  \intertext{and therefore due to \vref{kinetic-energy}: }
      B
  \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You Sir, are a gentleman and a scholar! ;-)