# Difference between ref, varioref and cleveref. Decision for a thesis

Tags: cross-referencing, best-practices, cleveref, varioref

How can one make a quick decision what the best "ref" for a thesis in `pdflatex` with `hyperref` is?

After a few hours reading I do not know more than

- `ref` is used by everyone who does not know about the other ~ref and works stable
- `\vref` [`varioref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/varioref) somehow works together with hyperref makes sometimes trouble with pagebreaks
- `\cref` in [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) [is still in beta(?)](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing) (**edit:** not in beta any more) and does the same like varioref

What are the essential questions that I have to ask myself to find out which method fits best?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36295/cross-reference-packages-which-to-use-which-conflict

Comment: Also, `cleveref` doesn't do the same as `varioref`. The former will try to figure what you're referencing, so `\cref{fig:figure}` can print e.g. *Figure 1*. `varioref` doesn't do this, but `\vref{fig:figure}` reference can print e.g. *1 on this page*, or *1 on the preceding page*. Only if the reference is more than two pages away, will the page number be printed, *1 on page 12*. The two can be used together though, see the `cleveref` manual.

Comment: OK i thought the packages would compete each other

Comment: The `cleveref` package has been around for a number of years and can't be considered to be "in beta" at this point.

Comment: Someone should correct the Wikipedia article then where it is called "beta".

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can certainly load both the [`varioref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/varioref) and the [`cleveref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/cleveref) with [`hyperref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/hyperref) provided that you load them in the following order

```
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

They all play very nicely together.

The `varioref` and `cleveref` weren't around when I did my thesis, but I'm working on a multi-chapter document at the moment in which I'm using both. Here is what I have found to be a good workflow:

- at a minimum, use `\cref` and friends (from `cleveref`) in favour of `\ref`. This means that, for example, you never have to worry about if you have to capitalize `Figure` or `figure` when referencing a `figure`; instead of saying `Figure \ref{fig:myfig}` you just use `\cref{fig:myfig}`. Maybe you'll change your mind and end up using `fig.`; in which case you can make the change globally using `\crefname`  and `\Crefname`
- use `\vref` and friends (from `varioref`) to refer to objects 'far away' from the current position in the text; my rule for the moment is to use `\vref` when referring to something in a different `section`. Some might say that this isn't very robust, but if the object you are referring to moves closer, `\vref` will still work fine. If you load `cleveref` then `\vref` becomes clever too, so you simply write `\vref{fig:myfig}`, not `Figure \vref{fig:myfig}`

The problems you describe with `varioref` occur if you allow `hyperlinks` to break, and the reference happens to break across a page that changes the reference from something like 'this page' to 'the next page'. In such a case, you'll have to tweak things manually- if you're using the work flow I've described above and only using `\vref` for 'far away' references and `\cref` for everything else, then this won't be an issue.

Here's a MWE to illustrate some of the features:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{varioref}       
\usepackage{hyperref}      
\usepackage{cleveref}     

% each of the following has two versions
%   \crefname{environmentname}{singular}{plural}, to be used mid-sentence
%   \Crefname{environmentname}{singular}{plural}, to be used at the beginning of a sentence
\crefname{table}{table}{tables}
\Crefname{table}{Table}{Tables}
\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}
\Crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \centering
  \rule{20pt}{20pt}
  \caption{My figure}
  \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\begin{itemize}
  \item Use \cref{fig:myfig} mid sentence.
  \item \Cref{fig:myfig} is appropriate for the beginning of a sentence.
  \item Use \vref{fig:myfig} mid sentence, note that it has become `clever'.
  \item \Vref{fig:myfig} is appropriate for the beginning of a sentence.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT following comments**

Quoting the [hyperref README](http://www.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README),

> There are too many problems with varioref. Nobody has time to   sort
>   them out. Therefore this package is now unsupported.

In fact, as noted by @Mico in [Lost labels using intertext with varioref and hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51636/lost-labels-using-intertext-with-varioref-and-hyperref), loading the `cleveref` package in addition to `varioref` and `hyperref` seems to eliminate a lot of the problems, as `cleveref` redefines `\vref` and friends to make them `clever`.

Comment: The 3rd item reads `Use Figure 1 on the preceding` I guess cref and vref should switch in the example, right?

Comment: I suggest to change the head to

`\crefname{table}{table}{tables}`
`\Crefname{table}{Table}{Tables}`
`\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}`
`\Crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures}`

Comment: @JonasStein that is a matter of personal preference, and precisely one of the reasons to use the `cleveref` :) however, since it's your question, I'll leave your edit :)

Comment: According to the [`hyperref` README](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README), the `varioref` package is not supported by the `hyperref` package due to various reasons. Doesn’t this apply any more?

Comment: @mhp good reference; I've never had any problems- perhaps it depends on which features one tries to use?

Comment: Perhaps @HeikoOberdiek knows more. At any rate, compatibility between the `hyperref` package and the `varioref` package would be a good thing.

Comment: @mhp - Loading the `cleveref` package (in addition to `varioref` and `hyperref`, of course) happens to eliminate the pesky little incompatibilities between `varioref` and `hyperref`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51640/5001 for more information on this.

Comment: Using `\vref` only for 'far-away' references kind of defeats the purpose of varioref, doesn't it?

Comment: The order or package loading is important, e.g. loading `varioref` before `hyperref` and `cleveref` before either seems to screw referencing.

Comment: @cmhughes Very nice answer, which is still up to date! One thing I'd like to mention: When referencing "larger" labeled items, such as chapters or sections, I generelly don't use `\vref`. Imho references to sections etc should never contain page numbers.