# cleveref & varioref : Missing \endcsname inserted

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, varioref

I read the excellent question [Difference between ref, varioref and cleveref. Decision for a thesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83037/difference-between-ref-varioref-and-cleveref-decision-for-a-thesis?newsletter=1&nlcode=102495|1202) and various doc on the net (the varioref package documentation) and tried to use it... but with many errors

An exemple :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=25mm,bottom=25mm,inner=25mm,outer=20mm,,marginparwidth=1cm,marginparsep=10pt}

\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[lmodern]
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{color,xcolor}


\ifpdf%
        \usepackage[pdftex,pagebackref=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
        \hypersetup{pdfstartview={FitH}, bookmarksnumbered={true}}
\else%
        \usepackage[hypertex=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\fi

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{varioref} 

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\section{Bla bla}\label{sec:bla}
\lipsum[1]

\newpage
\section{Second bla bla}
Test section 1 : 
\begin{itemize}
    \item with \verb"\ref" : \ref{sec:bla}
    \item with \verb"\vref" : \vref{sec:bla}
          = error "!Missing \verb"\endcsname" inserted" 
    \item with \verb"\cref" : \cref{sec:bla}
          = error "!Missing \verb"\endcsname" inserted"       
\end{itemize}

\newpage 
\section{Third bla bla}
Test section 1 : 
\begin{itemize}
    \item with \verb"\ref" : \ref{sec:bla}
    \item with \verb"\vref" : \vref{sec:bla}
          = error "!Missing \verb"\endcsname" inserted" 
    \item with \verb"\cref" : \cref{sec:bla}
          = error "!Missing \verb"\endcsname" inserted"       
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I get the error `!Missing \endcsname inserted` and more other after... (same error with vref as for cref.

How is it possible to resolve this ? I don't find an answer on this forum nor on the net.

I will use those packages (`vref` and `cref`) for my customized environnements, for exemple with such a macro-box :

```
\newtheorem{theoreme}{{\sffamily Théorème}}[section]

\newcommand{\boxthm}[2]
{{\colorbox{yellow}{\begin{minipage}{0.98\linewidth}
      \begin{theoreme}\label{thm:#1}
        {\sffamily ~\\#2}
      \end{theoreme}
\end{minipage}}}\\~}
```

I presume that if I can resolve the problem for a section, I also get the tip for all my macro-boxes (thm, definitions, algorithms, lemma, examples, ...) ?

Comment: Load `varioref` after `cleveref`. What's the purpose of loading `aeguill`? It's a *very* obsolete package. If you haven't the CM-Super fonts installed, use `lmodern`. Also giving both the `frenchb` and `francais` options to `babel` is redundant: use either one or simply `french`.

Comment: Load `lmodern` or install the CM-Super fonts.

Comment: indeed with 'varioref' after 'cleveref', the command vref works (but not wioth french label as seen in its documentation). But cref doesn't work ... the problem is always pending

Comment: Now I see! It's a completely different problem: it's caused by the colons in the labels.

Comment: code edited for correction given by egreg (thanks)

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that `varioref` and `cref` don't like `babel` shorthands in the labels. Since the colon has a special meaning for French, you get that strange errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=25mm,bottom=25mm,inner=25mm,outer=20mm,
  marginparwidth=1cm,marginparsep=10pt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype} % loads also ifpdf

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{varioref}

\ifpdf
  \usepackage[pagebackref=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
  \hypersetup{pdfstartview={FitH}, bookmarksnumbered={true}}
\else
  \usepackage[hypertex=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\fi

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{Bla bla}\label{sec-bla}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Second bla bla}
Test section 1 : 
\begin{itemize}
    \item with \verb|\ref| : \ref{sec-bla}
    \item with \verb|\vref| : \vref{sec-bla}
    \item with \verb|\cref| : \cref{sec-bla}
\end{itemize}

\newpage

\vref{sec-bla}
\end{document}
```

Some notes. The packages `ae` and `aeguill` are really obsolete and don't have really good metric files.

Better use the Type1 fonts that are provided by the CM-Super package (it depends on what distribution you're using how you install them) or say

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

Comment: Well ! So there is no possible solution ... It's a pity. Thank you anyway for your research.

Comment: Use `\label{sec:bla}`, then `\cref{sec\string:bla}` to work around the babel shorthand. (`\string` is mentioned in babel doc.)

Comment: Also note that `\shorthandoff{:}` inside a macro can’t be used as a workaround (or at least, not simply) as it has [no effect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167598) in a macro.

Answer (score 3):

I kind of found a workaround for that, but it is not super clean.

I load `cleveref`-package with the `french` option, and define a custom command `\citeref` (instead of `\cref`) as following

```
\newcommand{\citeref}[1]{
    \begin{otherlanguage}{british}
    \cref{#1}
    \end{otherlanguage}
}
```

Then it does work fine.

Comment: Looks like a nice solution. It's better, if you can, to add a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to show that it works.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).