# Changing the number of figure or equation automatically in text by changing the places of figures and equations

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, equations, numbering

Is it possible to automatically reference a figure and equations in text? I meant sth like bibliography references. Moreover, by changing the place of the figures or equations relevant figure or equation number can be changed automatically in text. Exp.:

> In remote sensing Equation 1. is applied widely.
>
> Equation 1.                     x= a+b

Comment: +1 because it's something newbies would want to know but you should really read a LaTeX introduction e.g. "A not so short introduction to LaTeX". It will provide this and many other things that you don't even know you need :)

Comment: @recluze I will just add that that you can find this document in many languages: http://ctan.org/pkg/lshort

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:abc}
  a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

The Theorem of Pythagoras says that as soon as equation \ref{eq:abc} is satisfied, ...
\end{document}
```

---

If this is what you mean, the preferred variant for cross-referencing equations is the one provided by the `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:abc}
  a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

The Theorem of Pythagoras says that as soon as equation~\eqref{eq:abc} is satisfied, ...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Be smart and use some smart package `:-)`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
  In remote sensing \cref{eq:myeqn} is applied widely. \Cref{eq:myeqn} is my equation.

\begin{equation}\label{eq:myeqn}
x = a + b
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

For details refer the documentation (run `texdoc cleveref` from command prompt). With `hyperref` loaded, the links can be made click-able. You may also be interested in `varioref` and `prettyref`. Please go through their documentation and also refer to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83051/11232) by @cmhughes.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answers by adding solutions for figures and tables. When you add figures and tables with their respective environments `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}` and `\begin{table} ... \end{table}` you can add a label to each using the `\label{}` command inside the \begin{} ... \end{}. A minor point but one I find useful is to add something to the label that identifies the kind. Hence, I add start the labels with `eq:` `fig:` and `tab:`. A reference to a figure in a figure object would then be made with \ref{fig:xxx} and th eobject defined as

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics{filename}
\caption{figure caption text}\label{fig:xxx}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Yes, good point