# Theorem/remark/proposition/etc tagging/labelling

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems

I have been wondering this for years, and never really had so much trouble that I couldn't bear not to know, but now I think I'll just ask and see if anyone knows.

It is common practice to label one's theorems, corollaries, remarks, etc, and then later type "as per Theorem `\ref{theoremname}`...", but what I want to know is if I can label my theorem so that I can just type "as per `\ref{whatever}`", and the reference tag will automatically use "Theorem 6.1" or whatever.

My reason is that I just upgraded a remark to a corollary, and even though the remark is labelled, I now have to find the references to that remark and change them from "Remark `\ref{tag}`" to "Corollary `\ref{tag}`".  Not a terribly recurring inconvenience, but just one of those things I'd like to know.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). About your question: you should have a look at the `cleveref` package.

Comment: `\thref` of the package `ntheorem` provides exactly that feature. In addition to that, it works better with the `hyperref` package because the "Theorem 6.1" becomes clickable instead of just "6.1".

Comment: One may also hack `fancyref`, I've used that sucessfully for a few books. It depends on label prefixing though, instead of looking at the context of the `\label`. IMO a package like `cleveref` mess with a bit too much for my taste.

Answer (score 3):

I use the `fncylab` package for this, which allows you to associate a macro expansion with every counter so that `\ref{<label>}` produces something more than just the value of the counter to which `<label>` corresponds.  For example,

```
\usepackage{fncylab}
\labelformat{theorem}{Theorem #1}
```

does exactly what you want.  I also tend to do `\labelformat{equation}{(#1)}` so that I don't have to bother with `\eqref` and, as a bonus, when used with `hyperref`, the entire `(<number>)` is hyperlinked rather than just the number.

Answer (score 3):

The [`cleveref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/cleveref) really helps to address this issue.

Instead of writing

> We see in Theorem \ref{thm:bigimportantthm}

you simply use

> We see in \cref{thm:bigimportantthm}

In your preamble, you tell the package how you want it to behave- in this example, you might write

```
% each of the following has two versions
%   \crefname{environmentname}{singular}{plural}, to be used mid-sentence
%   \Crefname{environmentname}{singular}{plural}, to be used at the beginning of a sentence
\crefname{theorem}{thm}{thms}
\Crefname{table}{Thms}{Thms}
```

You can easily get it working with the [`hyperref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/hyperref) and [`varioref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/varioref) as detailed in [Difference between ref, varioref and cleveref. Decision for a thesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83037/difference-between-ref-varioref-and-cleveref-decision-for-a-thesis/83051#83051)