# Why is my cross reference not working and some other questions

Tags: cross-referencing, syntax

I am a TEX beginner and I am now learning how to create a reference. I am reading the book "The Not So Short Introduction to LATEX2" by Oetiker, Partl, Hyna, Schlegl;  on page 42 section 2.8 Cross Reference, the code is written as

```
A reference to this section \label{sec:this} looks like:
"see section~\ref{sec:this} on page~\pageref{sec:this}"
```

And I am using CTex and WinEdt and my questions are:

1. I made a pdf file from the above code, but the section and page numbers are not highlighted and I cannot click on them. Why is it so?
2. I tried to make a reference to other pages by typing its page number like `{sec:37}`, but it does not work. How can I fix it?
3. What does the code `sec` actually mean? Is it arbitrary or a predefined syntax?
4. When I typed `\label{}`, a menu box named Labels (51) appeared, and there is a dropdown menus like `c:ISYAC`, `c:UNBOUND`, `c:UNIFBURN`,... etc... what is that? Do we have to choose from those list or can we write our own like `{sec:this}`?

Helps are greatly appreciated! Many many thanks!

Comment: Re #1: you will want to load the [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package via `\usepackage{hyperref}`. Re #2: References to page numbers are not supported this way: You need to add another `\label{foo}` to refer to another part of the document. Re #3: `sec` seems to be a prefix for section, it has no value for LaTeX, but is a help for you to remember what you referenced to is a section, and for example not a figure (commonly prefixed by `fig`). Re #5: Of course you can choose your own label name, and you should do so in fact, after all it's you who will need to remember them.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! To create cross-references that act like hyperlinks, you also need to load the `hyperref` package. For much more information on LaTeX's cross-referencing methods (including hyperref), be sure to check out the posting [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001).

Comment: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234". ;-)

Comment: Maybe worth a look: [Difference between ref, varioref and cleveref. Decision for a thesis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83037/4918).

Comment: @Tobi Yes, its better to use a concrete name.. :) And thanks for the info.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The general mechanism is to set an anchor some where in your document with `\label{<name>}`, where `<name>` can be a combination of numbers, letters, `:` and `-` (to be safe). These anchors must be set explicitly by the author, thats why `\ref{sec:47}` doesn’t work unless it is not defined by you. After setting up an anchor you can refer to it with `\ref{<name>}` (giving the corresponding counter, like chapter or section or equation or … number) or `\pageref{<name>}` (giving the corresponding page number).

Some author use identifiers like `sec:`, `eq:`, `thm:` etc. to make anchor names more human readable but this is not necessary for the mechanism to work.

**packages**
LaTeX’s mechanism can be extended by some packages:

- [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) makes references click-able hyper links (and has some more features).
- [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) finds the right names for labels and prints `\ref{anchor5}` as `section~5` instead of `5`, for instance.
- [`varioref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/varioref) compares the page numbers of anchor and reference and add text like `on previous page`, `on page 6` etc. automatically.
- [`nameref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref) can print the actual title of an anchor.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

% langage
\usepackage{babel}

% only for \lipsum blind text
\usepackage{lipsum}

% ref packages
\usepackage{nameref}
% folowing  must be in this order
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-10]

\section{My section}\label{sec:mysection}
\lipsum[1-22]

\section{References}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \verb+\ref{sec:mysection}+: \ref{sec:mysection}
    \item \verb+\pageref{sec:mysection}+: \pageref{sec:mysection}
    \item \verb+\cref{sec:mysection}+: \cref{sec:mysection}
    \item \verb+\cpageref{sec:mysection}+: \cpageref{sec:mysection}
    \item \verb+\vref{sec:mysection}+: \vref{sec:mysection}% already combined with \cref
    \item \verb+\vpageref{sec:mysection}+: \vpageref{sec:mysection}
    \item \verb+\nameref{sec:mysection}+: \nameref{sec:mysection}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: different references]

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is really useful! There is one more question, after it is referenced and linked, the section title, etc are red-boxed, can we change into a coloured text or something like that, a boxed text seems rather disturbing ;) Thanks very much!

Comment: yes, try `hyperref`'s `colorlinks` option (see sec. 3.5) … note the the boxes won't be printed anyway …