# compatibility cleveref and varioref amsmath

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, incompatibility, cleveref, varioref

I try to use cleveref and varioref and ams* packages together.
But I get some trouble, equations and sections label type seems to change and that does work well.

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,twoside,openright,a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage{hyperref}       %
\usepackage{amsmath}        % 
%\usepackage{amssymb}       % 
%\usepackage{mathrsfs}      % 
%\usepackage{amsthm}        % 
%\usepackage{amsfonts}      % 
%\usepackage{mathtools}     % 
%\usepackage{amsbsy, amstext, amscd, amsopn, amsxtra, upref}    % 

\usepackage{varioref}   %   
\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}

\section{first section} \label{sec1}

bla bla

\begin{equation}
    {sigma}={C}:{epsilon}
    \label{loiC}
\end{equation} 
\newpage

As we can see with \vref{sec1}, the reference does not work well and it is the same with \vref{loiC}.

\end{document}
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the packages in the correct order according to this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83037/difference-between-ref-varioref-and-cleveref-decision-for-a-thesis). The correct order is

```
\usepackage{varioref}   % 
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\usepackage{cleveref}
```