# Include the target page number in a hyperref description?

Tags: hyperref, page-numbering

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdfpagelabels=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{S1}
\label{s1}

\subsection{SS1}
\label{ss1}
Subsection 1
\newpage

\subsection{SS2}
\label{ss2}
Subsection 2
\newpage

\subsection{SS3}
\label{ss3}
Subsection 3.  For more info, see \hyperref[ss2]{Subsection 2, pg. How Do I Put The Target Page Number Here}.
\newpage

\end{document}
```

I want Subsection 3 to read: "Subsection 3.  For more info, see Subsection 2, pg. 3".

Comment: With `\pageref{ss2}`?

Comment: The [`varioref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/varioref) package and its `\vref` command might be of interest. You may want to load `cleveref` as well in that case. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83037/35864 are probably also worth a read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\pageref` would work here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdfpagelabels=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{S1}
\label{s1}

\subsection{SS1}
\label{ss1}
Subsection 1
\newpage

\subsection{SS2}
\label{ss2}
Subsection 2
\newpage

\subsection{SS3}
\label{ss3}
Subsection 3.  For more info, see \hyperref[ss2]{Subsection 2, pg. 
\pageref{ss2}}.
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to reference the page number without having to list the label id twice?

Comment: @mpr There are many possibilities, you could write a macro for it, or you look at some of the packages like in [Mico's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432063/121799) or in Moewe's comment. It really depends on the overall structure of your document. Notice also that the current version has certain advantages, it allows you to refer to a special bit in the subsection that is not on the same page as the head of the subsection.

Comment: Yeah it just occurred to me that a macro would be perfect for my setup, and also allow me to possibly use cref or other things later.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could employ the `cleveref` package and its highly customizable `\cref` and `\cpageref` commands.

(The colors in the following screenshot highlight the hyperlink targets; if you don't want colors, be sure to set the `allcolors=black` option while loading `hyperref`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdfpagelabels=true,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{subsection}{subsection}{subsections}
\crefname{page}{pg.}{pgs.}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{S1}\label{s1}
Section 1

\subsection{SS1}
\label{ss1}
Subsection 1.1
\newpage

\subsection{SS2}
\label{ss2}
Subsection 1.2
\newpage

\subsection{SS3}
\label{ss3}
Subsection 1.3.  For more info, see \Cref{ss2}, \cpageref{ss2}.

\end{document}
```