# \vref and input command

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, input, matlab2tikz, varioref

You've saved my life in some occasions, I am writing my master thesis and as I am working with MATLAB, I found a very useful MATLAB function which "translate" MATLAB images to TeX tikzpicture.

I decided to put the images in some folders and to call them with a "input" command, so i make everything like this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering  
    \input{./images/cap3/expmcwe/imax150t100.tex}
\caption{Results at time $t=100$ with $i_{max}=150$}
    \label{fig:imax150t100exp}
\end{figure}
```

and everything worked fine.

Then i tried to recall the images with the \vref command, recalling the labels i wrote (i made copy+paste to be sure!) and they doesn't recall anything. They write something like:"as we can see in figure ?? on page 79"; the page is correct but there is no figure number!

Just to be clear:

- I have uploaded all the necessary packages (I also put hyperref before varioref)
- I use TeXShop on Mac
- I have read all the manuals of the packages and found nothing
- I have to give my thesis to my tutor on thursday :)

I hope some of you have a piece of advice for me!

Thank you in advice to all of you.

[EDIT] I add some more informations:

I am writing in the {book} environment, and it's a bit complicated to write here how my file is because I have one main file with the heading of my thesis recalling all the chapters. However I'll put here the code of the document which stays after the \usepackage (which are something like 40, so i don't know if it is useful to put them all...

```
\begin{document}

\title{---}
\providecommand{\autore}{}
\providecommand{\coautore}{}
\providecommand{\cocoautore}{}                       
\providecommand{\principaladviser}{---}  
\providecommand{\corelatore}{}
\providecommand{\secondadviser}{}
\providecommand{\annoacc}{}
\providecommand{\corso}{\uppercase{---}}
\providecommand{\nomecorso}{}
\titlep
\thispagestyle{empty}

\cleardoublepage

\thispagestyle{empty} % citazione
    \begin{flushright}
    \vspace*{4 cm}
    \textit{---}\\
    \end{flushright}

 \newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\cleardoublepage

\thispagestyle{empty} % dedica
\begin{flushright}
%   \vspace*{4 cm}
%   \textit{ \\
%   }\\
%   []\\

%   \vspace{2cm}
%   \textit{}\\
%   ()
    \end{flushright}

     \newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

    %\maketitle
    \cleardoublepage
    \input{abstract}
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}

\frontmatter    
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents    

    \listoffigures

    \listoftables

    \lstlistoflistings

    \newpage
    \printnomenclature

\mainmatter


\pagestyle{fancy}
        %\fancyhead[LO]{} 
        %\fancyhead[RE]{}
        \fancyhead{}
        \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\slshape \leftmark}
        \fancyfoot{}
        \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
 \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
 \fancyfoot{}
 \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}}

    \input{introd}

    \input{cap1}
        \input{cap2}
        \input{cap3}
%    \input{cap4}
%    \input{cap5}
%    \input{cap6}

%   \input{conclusion}  

    \cleardoublepage 
    %\phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{bibliography}

    \cleardoublepage
    \input{acknowledgement}
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You should load `hyperref` *after* `varioref`. If that still doesn't work, try (surprising as this may sound at first) loading the `cleveref` package as well (*after* `hyperref`). See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51636/5001.

Comment: Thank you Mico, your advice worked for me, I am so relieved :)

Comment: pay attention anyway, because cleveref changes the reference names; for example one has to set the {lstlisting} name (\crefname{lstlisting}{code}{codes} or \crefname{lstlisting}{script}{scripts} and \Crefname{lstlisting}{code}{codes}) but also it repeats objects name: "see for example table \vref{tab:first}" gives as output:"see for example table table first"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key piece of information, I believe, is that you load the `hyperref` package before the `varioref` package.

A solution to the problems you report consists of (a) loading `varioref` *before* `hyperref` and (b) loading `cleveref` as well, after `hyperref`. The reason this works is that when `cleveref` is loaded, it checks if `varioref` is loaded and, if the answer is yes, modifies some of `varioref`'s internals in order to improve interoperability with `cleveref`. (Of course, for this to work `cleveref` must be loaded *after* `varioref`...) In the process, `varioref` also becomes more compatible -- I'm not sure if it's OK to say *fully* compatible -- with `hyperref`. For more information on this matter, see the posting [Lost labels using intertext with varioref and hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51636/5001).

In short, if you load the packages `varioref`, `hyperref`, and `cleveref` in this order, you should be able to use `\vref` without further problems.