# Conditional pageref for labels far away

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, labels, cleveref, varioref

Currently, within my thesis, I am numberings theorems (and remarks, etc.) with a global counter. This makes it difficult in the printed version to find the theorem if a reference is too far away from the label. Is there any simple way I can modify my reference commands to add a "on page XXX" in case of having lets say a 3 page gap between ref and label? Do you have any suggestions or experiences?

As far as I understood the documentations, packages such as varioref only support a one-page-diff condition; but even this I was not able to activate.

**Minimal working example:**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{blindtext} % lore ipsum...
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
  % example theorem:
  \begin{thm}\label{thm:foo}
    The future belongs to those who believe in their dreams.
  \end{thm}
  % generate more than 3 pages of text:
  \blindtext[20] 
  % reference:
  Reference to theorem \ref{thm:foo}. Here an automatic
  ``on page \pageref{thm:foo}'' would be nice.
\end{document}
```

**MWE for Mico (see discussion below):**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext} % lore ipsum...
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
  % theorem foo
  \begin{thm}\label{thm:foo}
      The future belongs to those who believe in their dreams, see (\vref{eqn:bar})
  \end{thm}

  % some pages of text...
  \blindtext[15]

  % cross-reference to theorem within equation which is labeled itself (same works for figures)
  \begin{align}\label{eqn:bar}
    a+b=c\quad\text{(cf. Theorem \vref{thm:foo})}
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Leads to

- `! Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'eqn:bar' will be lost.`
- `! Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label '4@xvr' will be lost.`
- several further warnings...

**(Partial) Solution (based on Christians idea)**
After playing around with Christians suggestion I came up with a solution (it SEEMS to work). I have to store the manipulated `\ref` command to `\vref` before `hyperref` is loaded. Then, I can use `\ref` as standard ref and `\vref` as optional "on page" version. For some strange reason this **only works together with babel**. It is important to add a "%" in order to avoid wrong spacing.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext} % lore ipsum...
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage[english]{babel} % < for some strange reason HAS to be loaded
%% --- ref manipulations as suggested by Christian Hupfer:
\makeatletter
\let\latex@@ref\ref

\newcounter{pagegaptreshhold}
\setcounter{pagegaptreshhold}{2}

\newcounter{tmpcntr}

\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{%
  \setcounter{tmpcntr}{\value{page}}%
  \addtocounter{tmpcntr}{-\getpagerefnumber{#1}}%
  \ifnum\value{tmpcntr} < 0 %
  \setcounter{tmpcntr}{\numexpr -1*\value{tmpcntr}}%
  \fi%
  \ifnum\value{tmpcntr} > \value{pagegaptreshhold}
  \latex@@ref{#1} on page \pageref{#1}%
  \else%
  \latex@@ref{#1}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
%% --- end cmhughes suggestion ---
\let\vref\ref
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
  % theorem foo
  \begin{thm}\label{thm:foo}
      The future belongs to those who believe in their dreams, see (\vref{eqn:bar})
  \end{thm}

  % some pages of text...
  \blindtext[30]

  % cross-reference to theorem within equation which is labeled itself (same works for figures)
  \begin{align}\label{eqn:bar}
    a+b=c\quad\text{(cf. Theorem \vref{thm:foo})}
  \end{align}
  In particular, we have now the choice between 
  \begin{itemize}
    \item ``on page''-if-too-far-away-style: Theorem \vref{thm:foo}
    \item classic style: Theorem \ref{thm:foo}
  \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A working example would be nice anyway

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Why did you delete your solution? I am still interested in that.

Comment: Because it does not work with `hyperref`

Comment: But it provides the option to adapt the page difference, even if I cannot use it ;-)

Comment: Thanks for providing a second MWE. Do check out the posting [Lost labels using intertext with varioref and hyperref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51636/5001). The recommended solution is to load the `cleveref` package as well (after `hyperref`), as doing so fixes a minor but long-standing incompatibility between `varioref` and `hyperref`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks again! I had already seen this solution, but `cleveref` changes so many things (adding extra "theorem" etc.) and throws further warnings ("destination with the same identifier ... duplicate ignored")... :-/ Can't I use just "the fix" from `cleveref` without introducing all the other inconveniences?

Comment: @matheburg - I'm afraid I'm not sure I understand what you mean. `cleveref` doesn't throw away warnings and error messages -- it actually fixes the problems that give rise to the warnings and error messages. If you need both `varioref` and `hyperref`, loading `cleveref` as well is -- for now at least -- the way to go. I use the macros of the `cleveref` package extensively in my own papers and can thus wholeheartedly recommend its use.

Comment: @Mico Oh, that's a misunderstanding: `cleveref` does not "throw away" errors and warnings, but it "throws new warnings"; but my major problem is that it introduces "theorem" before a ref of kind "thm:foo"; do you know how to deactivate this behaviour?

Comment: @matheburg: I've undeleted my solution and try to improve it, but at the moment, I don't recommend its usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@@ref\ref

\newcounter{pagegaptreshhold}
\setcounter{pagegaptreshhold}{2}

\newcounter{tmpcntr}

\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{%
  \setcounter{tmpcntr}{\value{page}}%
  \addtocounter{tmpcntr}{-\getpagerefnumber{#1}}%
  \ifnum\value{tmpcntr} < 0 %
  \setcounter{tmpcntr}{\numexpr -1*\value{tmpcntr}}%
  \fi%
  \ifnum\value{tmpcntr} > \value{pagegaptreshhold}
  \latex@@ref{#1} on page \pageref{#1}%
  \else%
  \latex@@ref{#1}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{first} 
In\ref{section::second} we will see that...
\blindtext[40]
\section{second} \label{section::second}
Here: \ref{section::second}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but `\setcounter{tmpcntr}{\value{page}}` is not reliable: it can be off by one, because the `\ref` could appear in a part of the paragraph that's then moved on the next page.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, unfortunately :-(

Comment: Nevertheless, it seems to be nice work! Thanks! Before I try: Do you think this is compatible with hyperref?

Comment: @matheburg: It should, but wait until I improved the code. It's a quick hack at the moment

Comment: @matheburg: Well, `hyperref` breaks this :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer For me it seems to work somehow, see post above. For some reason I have several small issues remaining: `babel` has to be loaded (no problem); **the 2-page difference does not seem to work**; I had to add a "%" to correct the spacing.

Comment: @matheburg: I will look again

Comment: @ChristianHupfer For some reason in my thesis the 2-page-diff seems to work; maybe another strange package interaction?

Comment: Finally, this did the job for me (see above). This is why I am accepting this answer.

Answer (score 7):

(Updated answer after the OP posted a second, more elaborate MWE.)

The `varioref` package implements the following decision rule with regard to generating page call-outs:

- If the item being cross-referenced and the cross-reference are on the same page, no page-related affix is produced;
- If the item being cross-referenced and the cross-reference are on adjoining pages, either "on the previous page" or "on the following page" is affixed to the cross-reference.
- If the item being cross-referenced and the cross-reference itself are two or more pages apart, a "on page x" affix is generated.

If you know in advance that there will be several pages between the cross-reference and the item being cross-referenced, you may also use the instruction `\fullref`, which is simpler (uses fewer machine cycles...) than `\vref`.

If you use both `varioref` and `hyperref`, you should load the `cleveref` package as well: Doing so fixes a (mild) conflict between the former two packages. If you load `cleveref`, the items' names ("equation", "theorem", etc) will be prefixed automatically to the cross-reference call-outs.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}    % lorem ipsum...
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}

\usepackage{varioref}     % for \vref and \fullref macros
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example

% theorem foo, with cross-reference to an equation
\begin{thm}\label{thm:foo}
The future belongs to those who believe in their dreams (see \vref{eqn:bar}). 
\end{thm}

% some pages of text...
\blindtext[15]

% equation bar, with cross-reference to a theorem 
\begin{align}\label{eqn:bar}
    a+b=c\quad\text{(cf.\ \fullref{thm:foo})}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Unfortunately, there are (at least) three issues: (1) Whenever I use a ref within an equation or figure which is labeled it throws errors and warnings; (2) I cannot change the behaviour (e.g. how much pages diff lead to the pageref); (3) I cannot use my old Lemma 1a) reference anymore..... (1), ofc., is the major problem!

Comment: @matheburg - Thanks for these additonal explanations. Just to make sure I understand the issue in point (1): You're trying to create cross-references *from* `equation` and `figure` environments *to* other, labelled items? Please confirm.

Comment: Confirmed: little dummy example: \begin{align}\label{eqn:foo}a + b = c\quad\text(cf. \vref{eqn:bar})}\end{align} The same for complex figures which include references to lemmas, equations, etc.

Comment: @matheburg - Your code snippet contains a syntax error. After I change the code to `\text{cf. \vref{eqn:bar}}`, I experience no problems with `\vref`.

Comment: Sorry for that, I did not properly check the syntax. I think the problem occurs in the combination with `hyperref`; I have added an MWE to my question :-) Many thanks for your efforts!